# How can exclude all version file of androidx library in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

I am trying to build gradle file but facing issue related to version file. I have to mention all version file in the packaging option.

```
 packagingOptions {
    //exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/androidx.coordinatorlayout_coordinatorlayout.version'
    exclude 'META-INF/androidx.arch.core_core-runtime.version'
    exclude 'META-INF/androidx.asynclayoutinflater_asynclayoutinflater.version'
    exclude 'META-INF/androidx.core_core.version'
    exclude 'META-INF/androidx.cursoradapter_cursoradapter.version'
    exclude 'META-INF/androidx.customview_customview.version'
    }
```

Is there any shortcut-way to write in one line to exclude all version file.

If anyone have idea. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: post the error and your build.gradle files

Comment: there are no error. I want to reduce to write number of lines. Every time build it comes up with new version file error.

Comment: that you have to exclude these appears strange to me. so what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
packagingOptions {
        exclude '/META-INF/*.version'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for response @Sundaram K,  I will check it.